# How to approach compilation errors with internal Text modules?

Tags: haskell, text, ghc

I have this problem:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘case-insensitive-1.2.0.5:Data.CaseInsensitive.Internal.CI
                                Text’
            with actual type ‘Text’
In the first argument of ‘named’, namely ‘n’
```

because:

```
Prelude Text.XML.Lens> :t named
named
  :: Applicative f =>
     case-insensitive-1.2.0.5:Data.CaseInsensitive.Internal.CI
       Data.Text.Internal.Text
     -> (Element -> f Element) -> Element -> f Element
```

My code imports `Data.Text` and relies on `OverloadedStrings`. What steps should I take to resolve issues like this? What are short term and long term fixes?

Comment: I don't know much about your code but can you do an `import qualified Data.Text as T` or `import Data.Text hiding (Text)`? this is usually the choice to do qualified imports to resolve namespace conflicts

Comment: If this uses OverloadedStrings, presumably the internal type which isn't exported has an `IsString` instance. In this case, you can just call the `fromString :: IsString a => String -> a`. Or you could just import that type... the `Data.CaseInsensitive` module exports it.

Comment: That doesn't give enough information. `CI Text` differs from `Text`, as the former uses a case-insensitive `Eq` instance. How did you try to ___use___ `named`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to commenters as I was able to find out why I'm having this problem.

**Short Answer**: Pay close attention to types and make sure you understand them (read documentation of any module you see in error message).

**Long Answer**:

Notice that the type contains spaces and `GHC` may break them down to multiple lines. `CI.Text` is means something different than `CI Text`.

```
‘case-insensitive-1.2.0.5:Data.CaseInsensitive.Internal.CI
Text’
```

`Text` here is not a type synonym of re-exported internal `Text` (common practice in libraries). `CI` is a type constructor and you cannot import it (for a reason - you have to stop and read documentation of anything you touch). You will understand why you can import `CI` **type** and `smart-constructors` like `mk` instead.